# How to retrieve image from particular folder on sdcard to drawable folder in android at runtime?

Tags: android

How can we retrieve or copy images from particular folder in sdcard to drawable folder at run time in android. Basically I want to show slideshow same as in given link but problem is that they are retrieving all images from drawable folder and i want to retrieve from some sdcard folder. I am beginner in android so please help me.

```
here is the link : 

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/image-gallery-example-in-android/
```

Answer (score 0):

Resources in res/drawable folder are compiled and optimized.
Please take a look at
[http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/topics/resources/android_resources-i18n_CreatingResources.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html).

If you want to use images on sdcard you have to load them from a file. Simple example would be:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());
jpgView.setImageDrawable(bitmap);
```

In short. Drawable folder is treated in a special way.

Argument imageFile is object of class File.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html

Variable jpgView is an instance of class ImageView. But this is just an example.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html

As far as your loop goes you would have to iterate through the files in a folder. Please consult documentation about that.

Comment: here what is imageFile and jpgView?? and how can i use this in loop to retrieve morethan 10 images sat 15 images??